# Callback function for fbq() function in Facebook pixel

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I have the following code

```
 fbq("track", "PageView");
   
  var fbp = document.cookie.split(";").filter(function(c) {
    return c.includes("_fbp=")
  }
    ).map(function (c) {
      return c.split("_fbp=")[1];
    });
```

as facebook pixel users know that when we call fbq() function it will create _fbp cookie in the browser,  I need to get fbp value from browser to send it to my API but  the problem here that the value of fbp is null because the fbq() don't finish it's work(create _fbp cookie).
so the problem is fbq() don't have callback function, what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue: when the page gets loaded for the first time, then our FB pixel server API is being called and at that very first time, we were not getting the fbp value since it was not generated yet.

In such case, we did a tweak to check if fbp is not generated, then held on FB pixel server API call for 2 seconds and then again checked for fbp and then call the API.

Though this will not completely solve the issue as it depends on the client network, it will surely increase the fbp % in the FB dashboard.